# Calling ASP.net Web Service from C# Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, desktop, invoke

I have a question. How can i invoke a web service and get the result from a C# desktop application. I am making a desktop app and I want it to be able to connect to my online ASP.net web services. How is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click your project node and select Add **Service** Reference.
2. Enter the URL where your service WSDL is located.  This is usually the URL of the service itself.
3. This generates a strongly-typed proxy class in a new Services References folder in your project.
4. Write code in your desktop app to instantiate the proxy class and invoke methods on it.  The rest works like magic. :)

AB Kolan was also correct, but Add **Web** Reference uses the old-style web services framework whereas Add **Service** References uses the new WCF stack.  Important note: It is **not** required that the service itself use WCF for you to use WCF on the client side.  WCF on the client is typically the best choice for any service, provided you can take a dependency on .NET 3.0 and above.

Answer (score 5):

Add a Web Reference to the webservice in your Desktop App project reference. Doing so would generate a Proxy for the Webservice called Reference.cs 
You can access your webservice using the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible the same way that you access web services from any other type of application, be it an ASP.NET page, a class library or windows service.

For an explanatory tutorial on the subject, see [Accessing a Web Service from a Desktop Application](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/munnamax/dbService04162006080340AM/dbService.aspx).

Comment: Or, he could use a Web reference and do it transparently.

Answer (score 0):

Will get help how to create a webservice and consume that service:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/consuming-web-service-in-Asp-Net-web-application/

Thanks