# ?wsdl php web service show no discovery information can not add reference

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I got this error. That's why I can't add a reference to my project.

Comment: this link worked bt some times its broken,please use (http or not or www)

Comment: I removed the dead link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add php web service on windows phone 7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672490/add-php-web-service-on-windows-phone-7-application)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a valid WSDL for your WebService. ([WSDL Documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wsdl/index.htm))

Try accessing the WebService's url with ?wsdl in the end.
Example:

`http://my.url.com/webServiceFile.aspx` becomes `http://my.url.com/webServiceFile.aspx?wsdl`

You should see something like [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wsdl/wsdl_example.htm). If you get an error message, then the WebService you're trying to access is not valid.

**EDIT:** I just realised that the URL field in your screenshot was blank because you did not enter anything in there. You need to know the URL of your WebService and then insert it into that field, making sure you have `?wsdl` at the end.

It needs to be something like:

```
http://<your domain>.com/<WebService file>.aspx?wsdl
```

Comment: Actually how can I access this web service from my C# form application.

Comment: Here's a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621440/calling-asp-net-web-service-from-c-sharp-application

Comment: If my answer helped, I'd really appreciate it if you +1 it or accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
```

before you print your wsdl.