# Add php web service on windows phone 7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am beginner in windows phone 7. today I create one application in windows phone 7. and develop hello world app. Now I want to start with my main app. And I added a PHP web service reference. But it show me below error to me.

> The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://mydomain.com/webservices/getLogin.php'. The content type
>   text/html of the response message does not match the content type of
>   the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom
>   encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented
>   properly. The first 80 bytes of the response were:
>   '{"userLogin":{"status":"NO","error":"Please enter valid user name /
>   password"}}'.
>
> If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service reference again.

I searched a lot but I didnt get proper solution. Please help me to resolve this issue. How to add php service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a simple [web request](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/04/01/using-webclient-and-httpwebrequest.aspx) to your service and parse incoming json.

If you really want to connect PHP service - [see this page](https://hubpages.com/technology/Using-the-NET-Service-Reference-to-consume-a-PHP-webservice).

Comment: as per your post i really need to create one service reference in c#. without doing this can i do like a .net service. i mean directly add service reference and use its object?

Answer (score 0):

To add service reference, you will have to provide web service's WSDL path in "Add Service Reference" URL.
(Refer this example :http://www.sanity-free.org/125/php_webservices_and_csharp_dotnet_soap_clients.html)

Your web service must have WSDL to Add Service Reference in Windows Phone App.